# How can I (compliantly) read from a tmpfile()?

Tags: c, fread, temporary-files

There are questions already for "how do I get the path created by `tmpfile()`?" but my understanding is that the standard does not guarantee that the file created has an accessible path. So, if the standard does not guarantee that, then what is the "standard" way to read from a tmpfile after you've written to it? (and of course, there's no point to a tmpfile that never gets written to, and there's no point writing if you never read it back)

I currently have this code:

```
struct foo {
    ...
};

FILE *fp = tmpfile();
struct foo x = { ... };
struct foo y = { ... };
int err = fwrite(&x, sizeof(struct foo), 1, fp);
printf("err: %x/%x\n", err, errno);
fflush(fp);

err = fread(&y, sizeof(struct foo), 1, fp);
printf("err: %x/%x\n", err, feof(fp));
```

which gives the output

```
err: 1/0
err: 0/1
```

I am running this code on onlinegdb.com because I don't have a compiler on this machine, so it could be that onlinegdb is not in compliance, but I would like to know whether it's that or if I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: I do not understand. Why does not having accessible path affect way of reading a file?

Comment: You can use [`tempnam()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tempnam-wtempnam-tmpnam-wtmpnam?view=msvc-170) to obtain a temporary file name and then open it as normal.

Comment: Use `rewind()` or `fseek()` to rewind the file before trying to read from it.  There is a unified read/write position; after writing, that position is at the end of the file.  So a read won't read anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I (compliantly) read from a tmpfile()?

Normally like from any other `FILE*`, with `fread`.

Your code is correct. It reads from the file. There is nothing to read on the end of the file, so `fread` returns 0 and `feof` is set.

If you want to read a file from the beginning after you have `fwrite`-tten to it, `fseek` it first.

Comment: ah, yes, this was the problem, I forgot to put in a call to `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` before I tried to fread. Thank you!